# Converting UK format date to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a value in SQL that represents a date, but it of type nvarchar. The value of the date is in the format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
```

I need to present this column via a view to a CCure 800 database in `DATETIME` format. I expected to use `CAST`/`CONVERT`; however, when using this, the following error is returned:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: There is similar question. Please see one of [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838344/sql-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in/38081347#38081347) that can be done.

Answer (score 17):

Please stop storing dates as strings, and *especially* as Unicode strings. Are you concerned that some future version of our calendar will have umlauts, pound signs, hieroglyphics, or Mandarin instead of numbers?

Store dates as dates. That is what those data types are for. In addition to not having to worry about invalid interpretations, you also get all of the benefits of things like `DATEPART` and `DATEADD`, and you don't have to worry about anyone stuffing nonsense into the column (anything from `31/02/2012` to `'I don''t want to enter a real date'`...

In the meantime, you just need to use a style number with `CONVERT` (this won't work reliably with `CAST`):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '13/06/2013 09:32', 103);
```

To make it work with `CAST`, you could set your `LANGUAGE` or `DATEFORMAT` settings accordingly, but you can't do this inside a view, and it makes the code very brittle anyhow IMHO.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT CAST('13/06/2013 09:32' AS DATETIME);
```

Or

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT CAST('13/06/2013 09:32' AS DATETIME);
```

By a very wide margin, I prefer the additional control `CONVERT` gives you, and almost unilaterally change all instances of `CAST` to `CONVERT`, even when this control is not needed, for consistency (why use `CAST` in some cases, and `CONVERT` when you need it, when you can just use `CONVERT` always?).

**EDIT**

To identify the garbage data that has snuck into your table because of a bad data type choice, do this (and then fix the data or, better yet, fix the data type so this doesn't happen again):

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT date_column FROM dbo.table_name WHERE ISDATE(date_column) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks - understand the theory on dates and you are quite right. However lets assume in this instance this isn't possible.

Comment: I tried using CONVERT also (as well as CAST) but the key to the issue is that it won't work when the format of the string is exactly "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM" - CONVERT wont convert this into a date.

Comment: Hi - when I press enter it adds the comment - appreciate the time spent!

Comment: @user2145047 can you show an *example* of the exact `CONVERT` command you tried, and what the *actual* value was instead of just saying `DD/MM/YYYY`? Maybe you aren't using `CONVERT` correctly, or maybe you have stored garbage data.

Comment: Thanks - here is what I am attempting:

Comment: Select CONVERT(DateTime,(CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DateTime,'25/12/2013 00:00'), 103) + ' 00:00'))

Comment: The value is coming from a table - I have added as a static string value for ease

Comment: That seems to work fine for me, but why do you need three converts, and why are you adding `' 00:00'`? Why not just: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '25/12/2013 00:00', 103);`?

Comment: There are legitemate circumstances where a date might be in a string format.  During data migration, for instance or importing data from a csv file.

Comment: Indeed, Aaron's answer is needlessly combative. I am about to attempt something similar and none of the approaches here actually work. I suspect the real answer might be rather more tedious, I am going to approach the problem with a combination of DATEFROMPARTS, splitting the string out using SUBSTRING on the "/" character and copious amounts of LEFT and RIGHT operators...

Comment: I think nearest one can go - select convert(varchar, getdate(), 0)

Comment: @Dibakar Nearest one can go - to what? Your statement takes a value that is already a `datetime` and converts it to a string. The OP has the opposite problem: they have a string like `'25/12/2013 00:00'` and need to convert it to a datetime, which won't work directly except when using certain languages/dateformats. Your statement doesn't solve that problem, because in order to use yours, you first have to convert the string. Also, please see [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score -1):

You may have multiple formats when importing a mess in a varchar column.

e.g. both US and UK date times, which are incompatible.

A couple of try_converts with a test for null may be enough.
No style number defaults to US and style number=103 for UK.  [DateOrdered] is the column being converted.

```
--Try US format first, if fails and returns null try UK format ...    
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(datetime,[DateOrdered]),TRY_CONVERT(datetime,[DateOrdered],103))
FROM ...
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 for list of styles
e.g. select try_convert(datetime,'01/04/21',3) is British with DD/MM/YY

Comment: Latest horror show I imported had 3 identical csv files.  Column specified as DateYYMMDD. Actually 2022-04-01 00:00:00.000 apart from one file where it was DD/MM/YY which of course had a single row exception at 36,726 lines in which was MM/DD/YYYY.
WHERE  TRY_CONVERT(datetime,[DateYYMMDD],3) is null -- is your friend to find the exceptions.