# analysis services convert date into datetime

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I'm using direct query mode between sql server database and Tabular project analysis services on one side and between analysis services and POWER BI on the other hand. when I filter by date in POWER BI analysis services convert the date into this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and SQL server answer with error:

> Converting a varchar data type to a datetime datatype create a value out of range.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have an example of the varchar data that is failing to convert?

Comment: i don't understand why the direct query engine convert a date to a datetime format like that: date = CASt(N'2018-07-23 00:00:00' as datetime) ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838344/sql-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838344/sql-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in)

Comment: i can't change the request, it is sent by the tabular ssas model