# System.Data.SqlClient.SQLException: The conversion of a varchar data type to datatime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Filter data between two dates I got the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: the Conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range.

My code is:

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT daytime AS DATE, COLUMN_2 AS SHIFT, COLUMN_3 AS 'PART NO',COLUMN_4 AS 'PART NAME',BSNO AS 'BASKET NUMBER',Spare1 AS MATERIAL, CAS6 AS 'CASCADE RINSE 6 TIME (sec)',DRY AS 'DRYER TIME (sec)',TEMP1 AS 'DRYER TEMP (°c)' FROM Table_2 WHERE daytime BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

I can't solve this error.

Comment: Use SQL Parameters always and pass the date without converting to string.

Comment: Pretty self explanatory, your datetime is not SQL valid.  What are the values of those 2 dates?  Use Debug mode and find out.  Also you should use parameters and not build out SQL statement this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838344/sql-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself converting a .Net DateTime value to a string for use in SQL, you're doing something **VERY** wrong.

The pattern demonstrated below contains several improvements over the code in the question. Most notably, the code in the question is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, while this code is not. But there are other improvements here, too.

```
//most datetime comparisons want an *exclusive* upper bound, but the BETWEEN operator bounds are inclusive on both ends
var sql = "SELECT daytime AS DATE, COLUMN_2 AS SHIFT, COLUMN_3 AS 'PART NO',COLUMN_4 AS 'PART NAME',BSNO AS 'BASKET NUMBER',Spare1 AS MATERIAL, CAS6 AS 'CASCADE RINSE 6 TIME (sec)',DRY AS 'DRYER TIME (sec)',TEMP1 AS 'DRYER TEMP (°c)' FROM Table_2 WHERE daytime >= @daytimeStart AND daytime < @daytimeEnd ;";
var dt = new DataTable();

//Don't try to re-use your connection object. 
// ADO.Net connection pooling means you should create a new connection for most queries
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{  //These using blocks guarantee the connection is closed, **even if an exception is thrown**. The original code would have left the connection open if you had an exception.

    //This is the correct way to include user data with your sql statement
    // **NEVER** use string concatenation to substitute values into SQL strings
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@daytimeStart", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dateTimePicker1.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@daytimeEnd", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dateTimePicker2.Value;

    //the Fill() method opens and closes the connection as needed
    da.Fill(dt);
}
metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Here it is again without the extra comments, so you can see how the new pattern isn't significantly longer than the original code in the question:

```
var sql = "SELECT daytime AS DATE, COLUMN_2 AS SHIFT, COLUMN_3 AS 'PART NO',COLUMN_4 AS 'PART NAME',BSNO AS 'BASKET NUMBER',Spare1 AS MATERIAL, CAS6 AS 'CASCADE RINSE 6 TIME (sec)',DRY AS 'DRYER TIME (sec)',TEMP1 AS 'DRYER TEMP (°c)' FROM Table_2 WHERE daytime >= @daytimeStart AND daytime < @daytimeEnd ;";

var dt = new DataTable();
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{   
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@daytimeStart", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dateTimePicker1.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@daytimeEnd", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =  dateTimePicker2.Value;

    da.Fill(dt);
}
metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```