# Data Type Selection for table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tab delimited flat file. One of the column called as earlydate has values like:

```
 18-08-2016 08:12:21
```

Can anyone suggest what would be best datatype to be in table. Other than VARCHAR OR NVARCHAR. I don't want to treat it like string.

Comment: is that not a datetime data type?

Comment: @RichBenner That's a datetime alright :)

Comment: If it looks like a `DATETIME`, smells like a `DATETIME`, and you want to treat it like a `DATETIME`...  by golly, you should make it a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @RichBenner: exactly, i selected the datatype of column as datetime2. now when i am inserting data with SSDT it is start throwing error as data conversion error. any suggestion

Comment: make it as simply DATETIME

Comment: @islechow: that is an entirely different question.

Comment: @islechow That is a completely different question.  But I assume it has to do with you using a UK-version of the date, rather than the ISO standard.

Comment: yes it is an UK Version

Comment: do i need to create seperate question guys........ :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275813/converting-uk-format-date-to-datetime

Comment: @RichBenner: Thanks Rich.... i will give a try........

Comment: Yeah, i'm in the UK too and the dates can be a bit of a pain. there's a few results if you google how to convert uk dates into datetime in sql. good luck :)

Comment: I'd suggest using `datetime2`, [**since even the documentation recommends it over regular `datetime`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)