# Convert date as '25/10/2022' to YYYY-MM-DD in Sql Server

Tags: sql, date

I need to convert date as '25/10/2022' to YYYY-MM-DD. I am doing it as

```
select convert(varchar,'25/10/2022',106);
```

But it showing me the date as it is without converting. How should I convert it into required format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting UK format date to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275813/converting-uk-format-date-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'25/10/2022',103) AS date_type_col
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE,'25/10/2022',103) , 121) AS text_type_col
```